# Modyfing lists of Strings inside list using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to modify Strings which are stored in ArrayList. It is not just about printing the modified list. After trimming the list will be pushed further down to the system.

The solution I came on is working, but I am wondering if I am using the full potential of Java 8 Streams.

Working(but far from perfect) solution:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<List<String>> listOfListsOfStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfListsOfStrings.add(Arrays.asList("abc ", "bd ", " asd ", "s"));
        listOfListsOfStrings.add(Arrays.asList("123 ", "45 ", " 753 ", "111"));
        listOfListsOfStrings.add(Arrays.asList("sdfg2 ", "b23d ", " as123d ", "1s1"));

        ArrayList<List<String>> newListOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<String> listOfStrings : listOfListsOfStrings) {
            List<String> newList = listOfStrings.stream().map(String::trim).collect(toList());
            newListOfLists.add(newList);
        }

        listOfListsOfStrings.forEach(list -> list.forEach(System.out::println));
        System.out.println("------------------");
        newListOfLists.forEach(list -> list.forEach(System.out::println));

    }
}
```

Comment: Remember to keep the balance between cool code and readable/understandable code. Do not force yourself to use them.

Comment: your method also a good method to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I was just wondering if there is a way to provide here smooth one-liner based on Java 8 Streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you’re after this:

```
    ArrayList<List<String>> newListOfLists = listOfListsOfStrings.stream()
            .map(list -> list.stream()
                    .map(String::trim)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

I am assuming that you are not allowed to modify the original list of lists. If you were, you could get your one-liner (even without using the stream API):

```
    listOfListsOfStrings.forEach(list -> list.replaceAll(String::trim));
```